# Node module is not updating

Tags: n

I updated my node module but now it is showing 2 diff version.

terminal:~$ sudo n 15.8.0

installed : v15.8.0 (with npm 7.5.1)

here what is v15.8.0 and what is 7.5.1

Comment: `installed: v15.8.0 (with npm 7.5.1)` is exactly what it says. The version of node is 15.8.0, and the version of npm is 7.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The prebuilt install of node comes with npm included as well, and it can be surprising when the npm version changes at the same time when you install a new or old node. To try and make that clearer, `n` lists the installed node version and the new npm version. So the version numbers are:

- node v15.8.0
- npm 7.5.1